# How to convert from Set to Set<Serializable> in java?

Tags: java, serialization, set

I have a Set which I need to use in another method, but this method takes as an input a `Set<Serializable>`.
Which is the best way to do this? Any suggestions acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a copy of your set:

```
Set<Serializable> serializableSet = new HashSet<Serializable>(yourSet);
```

(use `LinkedHashSet` if you need to preserve order).

This assumes that the elements of `yourSet` implement `Serializable`, of course.

Comment: Or a Guava `ImmutableSet`, if you have Guava in the project already, since it's just an array backing.

Comment: I see no point in making a copy. The code will be type-unsafe with or without the copying step.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik we don't know what the method does with the parameter. If it adds elements to the set and you've simply casted the problem away, you might get type safety issues in the next place the set is used.

Comment: You already _have_ type safety issues because you've accepted a raw Set with no guarantee that the elements are Serializable. Your copy has all these elements and the constructor doesn't even fail at runtime.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I didn't read it as being a raw Set, I suppose that is what OP says. Nonetheless, I'd say that taking a copy minimizes the radius of damage which can be caused by the method taking the `Set<Serializable>`. I think the clear solution here is to make the original set non-raw and the method parameter's type `Set<? extends Serializable>`; but I don't know how feasible that is in OP's code.

Comment: The way to minimize the radius of damage is manually iterating over each element and using `serializableSet.add(Serializable)` to enforce fail-fast behavior.

Comment: Also: if the original `Set` actually is raw, surely OP wouldn't be asking the question: the `Set` could just be passed to the method, no?

Comment: It could be passed with an "unchecked cast" warning, which is the same that happens with your solution. If we assume OP has a `Set<Something>` instead, then your solution produces an outright compiler error due to incompatible types.

Answer (score 1):

There are two warnings.  But it works.

```
void anotherMethod(Set<Serializable> arg) {
    System.out.println("called");
}

public void myMethod() {
    Set set = new HashSet<>(); // Set is a raw type.
                               // References to generic type Set<E>
                               // should be parameterized
    anotherMethod(set); // Type safety:
                        // The expression of type Set needs unchecked
                        // conversion to conform to Set<Serializable>
}
```

If `set` is a `Set<Object>` then you can call `anotherMethod((Set)set)`.

Comment: maybe you could use: void anotherMethod(Set<? implements Serializable> arg)